# How do I grab the variable names that are non-NA in a linear model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
summary(iris)

iris$married = c(0)
iris$death = c(0)
iris$test = c(0)

regressor = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
summary(regressor)

string = coef(summary(regressor))[2:summary(regressor)$fstatistic[2]+1,0]
string

names = c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Speciesversicolor","Speciesvirginica")
```

[image]

I can get it to output the non-na coefficients but I want to turn it into a list of characters like in 'names'. When I store it in 'string' it just becomes a weird num[1:4,0] type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to extract the names of the coefficients from the summary:

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
summary(iris)

iris$married = c(0)
iris$death = c(0)
iris$test = c(0)

regressor = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
summary <- summary(regressor)

string = row.names(summary$coefficients)[c(-1)]
string
```

Output string:

```
[1] "Sepal.Width"       "Petal.Length"      "Petal.Width"       "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.